# Why didn't Batman take the antidote with him when going to Arkham for Rachel?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, batman-begins

So in *Batman Begins*, Batman went to the Asylum in a hurry after learning from Rachel that she's going to pay Doctor Crane  a visit there. He expected Rachel to get in trouble there (otherwise, what would be the point of going?) and he knew Scarecrow has the drugs...

Why not take the antidote with him? Other than the fact that we'd lose a 15-minutes chase and run home to get her for the detox?

Comment: Because he's BATMAN!!!

Comment: Even the Batman forgets things sometimes.

Comment: No good explanation is given in the novel

Comment: @Richard how about the jr novel?

Comment: @phantom42 - I'm just checking the spinoff graphic novel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implication is that Fox only brought enough for **one dose**, and that was based directly on Bruce Wayne's own blood chemistry. When it became apparent that they'll need more (much more), Fox goes into town to collect the additional two sample doses, returns to drop them off at the Batcave and then heads *back* to Wayne Industries to get started on the next batch:

### From the film's [official novelisation](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Begins_(Book));

> “No, I just want you to know how hard it was. Bottom line, I synthesized an antidote.”
>   “Could you make more?”
>   “Planning on gassing yourself again?”
>   “You know how it is, Mr. Fox. You’re out on the town, looking for kicks . . . someone’s passing around the weaponized hallucinogens . . .”
>   Fox stood. “I’ll bring you what I have, but the antidote should serve as an inoculation for now.” He nodded to Alfred. “Alfred, always a pleasure. I’ll see myself out.”

### From the [film's script](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000187/quotes)

> **FOX:** *No. I just want you to know how hard it was. Bottom line, I synthesized an antidote.*
>
> **WAYNE:** *Could you make more?*
>
> **FOX:** *Planning on gassing yourself again?*
>
> **WAYNE:** *You know how it is, Mr. Fox … you’re out on the town, looking for kicks … someone’s passing around the weaponized
>   hallucinogens.*
>
> Fox shakes his head at Wayne, getting up to leave.
>
> **FOX:** ***I’ll bring you what I have*** – but the antidote should serve as inoculation for now. (To Alfred.) *Alfred, always a
>   pleasure.*

### And from the film's official [tie-in graphic novel](http://www.dccomics.com/graphic-novels/batman-begins-the-movie-and-other-tales-of-the-dark-knight)

[image]

So the simplest answer to your question; **Batman didn't take the antidote to Rachel because he didn't have it yet, and had he waited for Lucius Fox to bring him the extra doses from his lab (at Wayne Industries) before setting off, he would have lost valuable time in rescuing her.**